# Does a serialized hash column make more sense than an associated model/table for flexibility?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have been researching quite a bit and the general consensus is to avoid serialized hashes in a DB whenever possible, however the design I have lends itself to this structure, so I'm hoping to get some opinions and/or advice.  Here is the scenario:

I have a model/table `:products` which houses financial products.  Each product `has_many` investment strategies, which I had originally stored in a separate `:strategies` model/table.  Since each product has completely different strategies, and each strategy has different attributes, its become extremely difficult (and hacky) to manipulate each strategy's attributes into normalized, consistent columns (to the point where I have products that I simply cannot add to the application).  Additionally, a strategy's attributes can sometimes change based on the amount of money allocated to that strategy.

In order to solve this issue, I am looking into removing the `:strategies` model/table altogether and simply adding a *strategies* column to my `:products` model/table.  The new column would house a multi-dimensional hash of each product's strategies.  This option allows for tremendous flexibility from a data storage perspective.

My primary question is, do I lose any functionality by restructuring my database this way?  There will be times when I need to search a product by it's strategy's attributes and I  have read that searching within a multi-dimensional hash is difficult at best.  Is this considered bad practice?  Is there a third solution that I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantages of rolling with multiple tables for this design is you can leverage the database to protect your data with constraints, functions and triggers. The database is the only place you can protect your customers data with 100% confidence. These tried and true techniques have lost their luster in recent years and are viewed as cumbersome and/or unnecessary to those who do not understand them.

Hash based stores within relational databases are currently changing quickly due to popularity of nosql databases, however, traditionally it has been difficult to fully protect your customers data from the database with this implementation. Therefore, the application layer is where much of this protection lives. With that said, this is being innovated on and maybe someday they will solve it.

The big advantage of using the hash as a column in a table is you can get up and going more quickly while your figuring out your problem. In addition, you can pivot more easily because most modifications are made in the application layer on the fly.

Full text seaching and complex queries can also be a bit more difficult if your using an hash based store within a relational database.

General rule of thumb is if you need the data to safe and or have some complex reporting to do, go relational. Think a big financial services type app ;) Otherwise if your building a more social, data display style app, or just mocking things up there is nothing wrong with a serialized hash column. Most importantly remember to write tests so you can refactor more confidently if you choose wrong!

My $0.02

I would be curious to know which decision you choose and how it has worked out.